# A collection view inside a table view

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have the following implementation in the app, where there is a table view, where each table view cell holds a collection view.

[image]

Here, the number of cells in a collection view will depend on the data in a tableview cell and will be different for each row. For example, there are 3 cards in 1st row, 1 in 2nd row and 2 in 3rd row.

The issue is I am getting 3 collection view cells instead of 1 in the second cell.

Table view

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.groupedJobIds.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: JobTableViewCellCollection.CellReuseIdentifier) as? JobTableViewCellCollection {
        var jobIds = self.groupedJobIds[indexPath.row]
        cell.delegate = self
        if jobIds != [] {
            cell.bindJobs(jobIds)
        }
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Tableview cell / Collection view

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.jobIds.count  //It returns 1
}

//This method is called 3 times
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: JobCollectionViewCell.CellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? JobCollectionViewCell
    cell?.delegate = self
    cell?.bindJob(jobId)
    return cell!
}
```

As you can see, the first method returns 1 as numberOfItemsInSection. But the second method is called 3 times. Am I missing something?

Comment: Add code for your tableview datasource and delegate methods as well.

Comment: how many `UICollectionView` instances do you have? are they sharing the same instance of what conforms to `UICollectionViewDataSource`? because you have 3 cells visible and you got called the delegate 3 times... it cannot be a coincidence, but it is not clear how you have set up the delegates for the data-source.

Comment: yeah. could you provide delegate and datasource for tableView? cellForRowAt and numberOfItemsInSection.

Comment: Maybe some `reloadData` (or related method) calls?... How many items do you see? You could set a breakpoint in order to see what is causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this. I missed the *reloadData()* on the collection view which was causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `dequeueReusableCell` method of the table view, which is causing the problem.
Can you try a new collection view on table view every time it load?

Answer (score 0):

You should populate your UICollectionView from the right source. In your code you populate all of your collection view cells from the same `self.groupedJobIds`. You should either populate your collection view from table view cell's bound jobIds or keep an array of jobId groups in your UIViewController and populate from there.